Work with multiple where statements with different conditions
I have the below SQL logic made up of three where statements each seperated by "OR".  My goal is to retrieve all data within the first where statement, but exclude only those records that meet the criteria in the second two where statements.  When I run it as is I get all the records. I think it's because of the first where statement, but I can't figure out how to change it so it only excludes the records that meet the criteria in the last two where statements.  Any help you can provide to rewrite this logic is greatly appreciated.
WHERE 
(
    (ord_billto = 'CATGRI'
    AND o.ord_status = 'CMP'
    AND o.ord_startdate >= @StartDate and o.ord_startdate < @EndDate+1
    AND o.ord_invoicestatus = 'XIN')
OR
    (o.ord_billto = 'CATGRI'
    AND o.ord_status = 'CMP'
    AND o.ord_startdate >= @StartDate and o.ord_startdate < @EndDate+1
    AND o.ord_invoicestatus = 'XIN'
    AND o.ord_revtype4 IN ('GRIFF3')
    AND s.cmp_id NOT IN ('CATLAF10','ORDBEL', 'SKYLIV','SKYPLY'))
OR
    (o.ord_billto = 'CATGRI'
    AND o.ord_status = 'CMP'
    AND o.ord_startdate >= @StartDate and o.ord_startdate < @EndDate+1
    AND o.ord_invoicestatus = 'XIN'
    AND o.ord_revtype4 IN ('GRIFF1')
    AND s.cmp_id NOT IN ('CATGRI02','CATWAC01'))
)


Could this perhaps help you? sql query with multiple where statements

The condition looks fine to me. The usual reason complex conditions like this return all rows is because it's not parenthesized correctly, but this looks good.

Please post sample data and desired results.

Aside: You can use BETWEEN for the date conditions.

@Barmar - not for inclusive start date and exclusive end date.  The >= and < date range check is best practice.

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

I need the conditions seperated because you could have for example cmp_id = CATGRI02 in both GRIFF1 and GRIFF3.  I only want to exclude that cmp_id when it is under revtype4 = GRIFF1.

@TN But they had to add 1 to make it exclusive. If you use BETWEEN you don't need that.

(repost) Do you perhaps need WHERE (conditions 1) AND NOT (conditions 2) AND NOT (conditions 3) or equivalently WHERE (conditions 1) AND NOT (conditions 2 OR conditions 3)? If so, you can also trim the second and third conditions down to just check the o.ord_revtype4 and s.cmp_id values.

@Barmar  I thought the logic worked based on what I have done in the past,  but it is only giving results related to the first where statement.  It won't exclude those records that meet the last two where statements.

When you combine conditions with OR, it includes rows that match each set of conditions, it doesn't exclude them.

You should simplify it. The billto, status, and startdate conditions are the same for all of them, so take them out of the OR.

@Barmar  The logic itself is made up of 8 different queries getting pushed to Temp tables. The final result is a basic table in SSRS that looks like an excel spreadsheet. I'm just trying to figure out  to get those records excluded.   I would past the logic, but it's way to large to post here.

How is that relevant?

@Barmar  Forgive the lack of knowledge about SQL. I know the basics, but not to advanced in the subject.

I don't really care about the SSRS stuff, just this one query. It should return only the rows that meet any of these 3 conditions. Please post sample input data.

@Chris - Your statement about having "8 different queries getting pushed to Temp tables" might completely change the problem. Are you attempting to modify the conditions in each of the 8 different queries, so that they do not produce overlapping results, or are you past that point and need to select data from one temp table while excluding data contained in another temp table? If the latter, perhaps you need something like SELECT * FROM #Temp1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM #Temp2 or SELECT T1.* FROM #Temp1 T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Temp2 T2 WHERE T2.KeyColumn1 = T1.KeyColumn1 AND ...).

To "retrieve all data within the first [condition], but exclude ... those records that meet the criteria in the second two [conditions]", try:
WHERE (
    ord_billto = 'CATGRI'
    AND o.ord_status = 'CMP'
    AND o.ord_startdate >= @StartDate and o.ord_startdate < @EndDate+1
    AND o.ord_invoicestatus = 'XIN'
)
AND NOT (
    o.ord_revtype4 IN ('GRIFF3')
    AND s.cmp_id NOT IN ('CATLAF10','ORDBEL', 'SKYLIV','SKYPLY')
)
AND NOT (
    o.ord_revtype4 IN ('GRIFF1')
    AND s.cmp_id NOT IN ('CATGRI02','CATWAC01')
)

(Redundant conditions have been trimmed.)
Or equivalently:
WHERE (
    ord_billto = 'CATGRI'
    AND o.ord_status = 'CMP'
    AND o.ord_startdate >= @StartDate and o.ord_startdate < @EndDate+1
    AND o.ord_invoicestatus = 'XIN'
)
AND NOT (
    (
        o.ord_revtype4 IN ('GRIFF3')
        AND s.cmp_id NOT IN ('CATLAF10','ORDBEL', 'SKYLIV','SKYPLY')
    )
    OR (
        o.ord_revtype4 IN ('GRIFF1')
        AND s.cmp_id NOT IN ('CATGRI02','CATWAC01')
    )
)


Thank you everyone for your help.   Your recommendations helped solve my problem.  As somewhat of a novice in SQL all your input will help in my development learning SQL.

@ Dale K No I am not, but I did find where it's at.

This method is not the most efficient, but I often prefer it when excluding data. It allows you to identify exactly which records are being excluded by simply running the subquery alone. You can then check that it's excluding what you want it to, and not excluding things you don't;
SELECT * FROM [TABLE]

WHERE ord_billto = 'CATGRI'
    AND o.ord_status = 'CMP'
    AND o.ord_startdate >= @StartDate and o.ord_startdate < @EndDate+1
    AND o.ord_invoicestatus = 'XIN'

AND [PRIMARYKEY] NOT IN (SELECT [PRIMARYKEY] FROM [TABLE]
                        WHERE o.ord_billto = 'CATGRI'
                        AND o.ord_status = 'CMP'
                        AND o.ord_invoicestatus = 'XIN'
                        AND o.ord_startdate >= @StartDate and o.ord_startdate < @EndDate+1
                        AND (

                            (o.ord_revtype4 IN ('GRIFF3')
                            AND s.cmp_id NOT IN ('CATLAF10','ORDBEL', 'SKYLIV','SKYPLY'))
                        OR
                            (o.ord_revtype4 IN ('GRIFF1')
                            AND s.cmp_id NOT IN ('CATGRI02','CATWAC01'))
                            )
                        )


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
